# Is there a clean way to check if a given user exists on a computer through python?

Tags: python, operating-system, pwd

Currently I am using pwd.getpwall(), which shows me the entire password database. But I just want the users accounts of the computer. And with using getpwall() I am unable to do this ...

```
if 'foo' in pwd.getpwall():
     do stuff
```

since pwd.getpwall() returns a list of objects. And if I wanted to check if a user exist I would have to do a loop. I assume there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

In [the same page of the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwnam):

> ```
> pwd.getpwnam(name)
> ```
>
> Return the password database entry for the given user name.

This is the result for an existent and an inexistent user:

```
>>> import pwd
>>> pwd.getpwnam('root')
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='root', pw_passwd='*', pw_uid=0, pw_gid=0, pw_gecos='System Administrator', pw_dir='/var/root', pw_shell='/bin/sh')
>>> pwd.getpwnam('invaliduser')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found: invaliduser'
```

Therefore you can do:

```
try:
    pwd.getpwnam(name)
except KeyError:
    # Handle non existent user
    pass
else:
    # Handle existing user
    pass
```

Note: the `in` operator would do a loop anyways to check if a given item is in a list ([ref](http://pyref.infogami.com/in)).

Answer (score 1):

`pwd.getpwnam` raises a `KeyError`if the user does not exist:

```
def getuser(name):
    try:
        return pwd.getpwnam(name)
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
>>> [x.pw_name for x in pwd.getpwall()]
```

Store the list and just check for `username in list`